# How to fix duplicated backend call problem on react native

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native, redux, react-navigation

We are using mongoDB and redux on our project. When we navigate to a page get the id of the player which we want to retrieve from redux store and pass it to the component. The screenshot below shows my console.log to this store with the id we got. We also get the attributes of the player and details. The strange thing is that we cannot see our result on the page. But if we go back and enter the page again and do this for exactly three times than we have the result. I used console.log for tracing and I see that in a single page load I got this console.log s three times. This is a very strange issue and we could not understand why this happens. Is it because of navigation, redux, or something else? I am pasting the output on a single page load under the code.

```js
const { id } = route.params;
console.log(" on players detail page id is: " + id);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(playerCardActions.getPlayerCardInfo(id));
    dispatch(playerAttributeActions.fetchPlayerAttributes(id));
}, [dispatch]);

const playerCard = useSelector(
    (state) => state.playerCardStore.selectedPlayerCard
);
console.log(" on players detail page playercard is: " + playerCard);

const playerAttribute = useSelector(
    (state) => state.playerAttributeStore.selectedPlayerAttribute
);

console.log(" on players details page playerattr is: " + playerAttribute);
```

on players detail page id is: 604a8e1d83a1a09b8a61afb9

on players detail page playercard is: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object   Object],[object Object]

on players details page playerattr is: [object Object]

on players detail page id is: 604a8e1d83a1a09b8a61afb9

on players detail page playercard is: [object Object]

on players details page playerattr is: [object Object]

on players detail page id is: 604a8e1d83a1a09b8a61afb9

on players detail page playercard is: [object Object]

on players details page playerattr is: [object Object]

Below you can find the store code

```
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

import playerCardReducer from "./reducers/playerCard-reducer";
import playerAttributeReducer from "./reducers/playerAttribute-reducer";
import playerStatisticsReducer from "./reducers/playerStatistics-reducer";
import playerDetailsReducer from "./reducers/playerDetails-reducer";
import playerReducer from "./reducers/player-reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    playerCardStore: playerCardReducer,
    playerAttributeStore: playerAttributeReducer,
    playerStatisticsStore: playerStatisticsReducer,
    playerDetailsStore: playerDetailsReducer,
    playerStore: playerReducer,
});

const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
export default createStore(rootReducer, middleware);
```

I am also adding the one of the reducer's code below

```
import {
    CREATE_PLAYER_DETAILS,
    GET_DETAILS_OF_PLAYER,
    UPDATE_PLAYER_DETAILS,
} from "../actions/playerDetails-action";
import PlayerDetails from "../../models/PlayerDetails";

const initialState = {
    selectedPlayerDetails: null,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_DETAILS_OF_PLAYER:
            return { selectedPlayerDetails: action.selectedPlayerDetails };
        case CREATE_PLAYER_DETAILS:
            const newDetails = new PlayerDetails(
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.playerID,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.phone,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.email,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.height,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.weight,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.playerCardId,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.attributesId,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.statisticsId
            );

            return (state.selectedPlayerDetails = newDetails);
        case UPDATE_PLAYER_DETAILS:
            const updatedDetails = new PlayerStatistics(
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.playerID,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.phone,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.email,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.height,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.weight,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.playerCardId,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.attributesId,
                action.selectedPlayerDetails.statisticsId
            );
            return (state.selectedPlayerDetails = updatedDetails);
    }
    return state;
};
```

Comment: please share store code

Comment: I suggest you use vscode with the [eslint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) so you would see you got a [missing dependency](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920), create-react app should have set up the eslint rules for your project. You are missing a dependency of id in your effect. Your question is missing the action, reducer and selector but with the information given in your question I'd have to guess you did something wrong and that is why it's not working for you.

Comment: Thank you for comments, I have added the codes you asked and now gonna look for the eslint and if you are right about the dependencies